# How can I improve the error reporting of this C open call in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, file-io

As it stands the code looks like this:

```
fd = open(filename, openflag, perm);
```

I then call perror on open and receive

```
open: No error
open: No error
open: No error
open: No error
```

The final error call is:

```
die(1, "open_fds: File open error");
```

Yielding

```
SIO_ERROR: open_fds: File open error
```

What can I do to get more meaningful error messages?

Notes: This is for a Windows environment and I'm relatively new to C.

Comment: [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) returns -1 to indicate an error ... and you shouldn't call `perror()` for any other result.

Comment: What did `open` return? If fd is nonnegative, then there is no error, like perror tells you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perror` or you can use `strerror(errno)` on Windows and both should work, here's an example of the latter:

```
int fd = open("some_made_up_file_name.txt", O_RDONLY);
if(fd < 0)
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
```

In this case I'd get:

> No such file or directory

Because that file I'm trying to open doesn't exist and I didn't tell it to create in this case. You need to make sure you check the return from `open()`, `< 0` and you have a problem.

Comment: I'm getting a -1 return code now, the file does exist. The code is spawning a 8 threads to write to a file, and I am getting 8 file open OK messages. I was looking for something more like a stack trace perhaps that would be dumped to stdout.

Comment: @ChrisKing - getting stack traces will be based on how you're compiling. Are you using an IDE, or an editor and MingGW?

Comment: I'm compiling using VS now, but I'm running this application on a client afterwards as my build machine is easily networkable to the client testbed.

Comment: @ChrisKing - OK, sorry, not really familiar with VS, but it looks like you can build with debug symbols see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx) for information on that. If it is what I think then you can cause a crash at the point of file open failure and you should be able to get a back trace that VS could open. Good luck!

Comment: I believe this should help out as well http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/postmortem-debugging/185300443

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen seen, `perror` works fine in windows also. 
Do you know if `open` did fail (what did it return) & if it did fail, why did it fail in your case? Was the file not there or was it a permissions issue? And why did `perror` print the "No error" message 4 times?

What is the `die` function - as far as I know it's not a standard function? What does it do to print an error message?

On windows, you can also use [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the error. (other than `errno` and `perror`).

You can use [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to format the error message corresponding to the error code returned by GetLastError.

Comment: +1 for GetLastError.  It's not cross-platform, but it's often more detailed than errno and perror.

Comment: It is failing with a -1 now. No further information is being displayed at this time. I should restate there are 8 of those messages, I didn't paste correctly. Also there are 8 threads writing to files in the code. What is weird is that it gives the OK message then fails on the last always.